# IE9 jquery ajax post request randomly causing bad request (400), tomcat receives post parameters as 'null'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, tomcat6, bad-request, http-status-code-400

We have production application where we randomly seeing Bad request response (status code = 400) in apache access logs.

- Happens only for IE9 users - (Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0).
- We have tried to re-produce for same URLs (scenarios) - we are not able re-produce
- Tomcat receives all parameters as null and ends-up with null pointer exception. We do have a error page forwarding for exception, but client receives 400-Bad request.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: We are still researching the issue. It seems the issue is not related corporate firewall as mentioned by @Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with AJAX when users are behind a corporate firewall. Sometimes the request seems to get altered in unpredictable ways. If you are not able to reproduce with the same browser this might be worth looking into.

Unfortunately if this is the issue there isn't a lot you can do except not use AJAX for those parts.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. We have very few post parameters, so if POST is a problematic, Do you think changing to GET would solve the issue?